# How do I implement LogInWithDifferentMicrosoftAccount() in blazor server application?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EDIMonitor.Data
{
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginLogoutController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string redirectUri)
        {
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = redirectUri
            };

            return Challenge(props, MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [HttpGet("logout")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("https://localhost:44328/");
        }

        [HttpGet("loginwithdifferentaccount")]
        public IActionResult LoginWithDifferenttAccount(string redirectUri)
        {
            // Specify the authentication scheme for Microsoft Account
            var authenticationScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            // Redirect to the login action with the specified authentication scheme
            return RedirectToAction("Login", new { redirectUri, authenticationScheme });
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried code above but it automatically logs me in. I'd like to be able to log in with different account...please help. I run out of ideas on how to implement this missing feature